# check if turbogears public file exists

Tags: path, turbogears

I am new to turbogears and have an app that I am creating with multiple directories under public/media/ballots.  I need to see if a directory exists.

```
path = "public/media/ballots/" + x['directoryName']
#return path
if os.path.exists(path):
                listing = os.listdir(path)
                i=0
                for infile in listing:
                   #find path for ballot1, ballot2, etc from files in directory
                   i +=1
                   Ballot = "Ballot" +str(i) 
                   x['Ballot']= infile
                return x
else:
    return "false"
```

I've tried multiple ways of defining the path: "/media/ballots/", "./media/ballots/", "media/ballots".  But the os.path.exists(path) always returns false.  I'm not sure how TG is accessing the public files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the path="projectname/public/media/ballots/"

Comment: actually that wont work as it depends on running the project from inside the project directory itself. Which is not usually true at deploy time.

Answer (score 7):

**tg.config['paths']['static_files']** will give you the absolute path of the public directory. You can then use *os.path.join* to chain it to the path of your files relative to the public one.

Comment: that is exact answer, to the question. do not trust relative paths.